# Matrix vector v =[x, y, 1] multiplication to get v' =[x/y, y, w]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I make a matrix (or multiple matrices) which, when multiplied by the vector `v =[x, y, 1]`, I get the vector `v' =[x/y, y, w]` where `w` can be any number (`w` is not important, the purpose is to get the `x/y, y` part)?

Comment: I don't think such a matrix can exist since you can't form a quotient by multiples of matrices.

Comment: You cannot. Note that matrix multiplication is linear, so doubling the input would double the output. The first component of your desired operation would remain the same.

Comment: I see... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this 3x3 Matrix(after the first 3 numbers, and after six numbers a new matrix line starts, I am new to this page and can't use formatting yet):
M=[1/y,0,0;
    0 ,1,0;
    0 ,1,w]

Comment: Unless I somehow understood your question wrong...

Comment: But I cant use the variables `x, y` in the matrix (I can use only constants in the matrix).

Comment: Then it is impossible.